# On a asymptotic equality

Tags: limits

Let's say that the following asymptotic equality holds, namely

$$ f(x)\sim g(x).$$

My question, if the above asymptotic equation holds, then the asymptotic equality

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} =1$$

also holds?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=g(x)$ is meaningless

Comment: @gimusi Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @RobertZ it should be $$\lim_{x\to\infty} (f(x)-g(x))=0 \not\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} =1$$ eg $f=1/x$ $g=1/x^2$ and $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} =1 \not\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to\infty} (f(x)-g(x))=0 $$ eg $f=x^2+x$ and $g=x^2$, am  right?

Comment: @gimusi Yes, those implications do not hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that **by definition**

$$f(x)\sim g(x) \iff \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} =1$$

or also, as an alternative and more general definition useful when $g$ has zeroes in every neighbourhood of $x_0$, that for $x\to x_0$ with $\omega(x)\to 0$

$$f(x)\sim g(x) \iff f(x)-g(x)=o(g(x)) \iff f(x)-g(x)=\omega(x)g(x)$$

Comment: @gimusi Last question, $$ f(x)\sim g(x) \Rightarrow lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)$$ obviously holds?

Comment: @BrightChancellor Yes this holds as a necessary condition it we consider equal also the limit when $f,g\to \infty$.